# File convert error on hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to upload a word document on hosting server with asp.net C# and try convert into HTML page but getting below error.

> 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

here is my code which can i used for upload and convert word file.

```
object missingType = Type.Missing;
object readOnly = true;
object isVisible = false;
object documentFormat = 8;
string randomName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
object htmlFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + randomName +".htm";

string directoryPath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + randomName + "_files";

//Upload the word document and save to Temp folder
FileUploadUsage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadUsage.PostedFile.FileName));

object fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + FileUploadUsage.PostedFile.FileName;

//Open the word document in background
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application applicationclass = new         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

applicationclass.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                                ref readOnly,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref isVisible,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType);
applicationclass.Visible = false;
Document document = applicationclass.ActiveDocument;

//Save the word document as HTML file
document.SaveAs(ref htmlFilePath, ref documentFormat, ref missingType,
                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                ref missingType);

//Close the word document
document.Close(ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType);

//Delete the Uploaded Word File
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/ProductHTML/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadUsage.PostedFile.FileName));

//Read the Html File as Byte Array and Display it on browser
byte[] bytes;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(htmlFilePath.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);
    bytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    fs.Close();
}

Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();                
Response.End();
```

Comment: Did you verify that Word is installed on that server?

Comment: no. how can i verify that? if not possible to install on server then what can i do?

Comment: Look into [OpenXML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)

Answer (score 0):

You are working on a remote server which does not have Word installed.

You must install word on the server if you want it to work, if you don't have access to the server then you are out of luck, you cannot do it.

Comment: Word to html without office? well, I don't know any way, it will be easier to have them converted before they are sent to the server...